# Можно ли этот код jQuery превратить в React компонент?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, create-react-app

Вот код:

```js
$('img.img-svg').each(function(){
    var $img = $(this);
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');
    $.get(imgURL, function(data) {
        var $svg = $(data).find('svg');
        if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
        }
        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
        if(!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
            $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'))
        }
        $img.replaceWith($svg);
    }, 'xml');
});
```

Этот код превращает все img с определённым классом в svg (ну разумеется img с расширением svg)
Так я переписываю свой сайт на react (create-react-app) мне нужно это как-то переписать туда.

Точно не понимаю как оно должно выглядеть в реакте, но скорее всего просто компонент в который отдаётся ссылка на картинку и alt через пропсы и он магией превращает её в svg

Comment: обычная картинка с каким то class превращается в svg ?

Comment: @MaximLensky нет, есть например ```<img src="assets/image.svg" /> ``` и оно вытаскивает содержимое файла .svg и заменяет картинку на этот код

Comment: @MaximLensky вы прочтите ещё раз, картинка которую туда суют должна быть разрешения .svg

Comment: сорри - я проверю щас

Comment: @MaximLensky этот код нужен что бы использовать css стили такие как fill к "img"

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/BaoKvmw - хоть убей не работает

Comment: @MaximLensky щас сделаю что б работало и скану ссылку, на проде работало

Comment: @MaximLensky скорее всего это из-за того что оно не может послать get запрос на другой сайт, надо локально это сделать

Comment: я так и думал..ладно проехали